# Problems using PRAW (searching and posting)

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I am trying to write a small program with PRAW the python library for Reddit API, and I am searching and posting to reddit greek content.

For example I have the following function:

```
def find_if_posted(usr, title, url):
    for content in usr.search(title):
        return True
    for content in usr.search(url):
        return True
    return False
```

which tries to search if there is a post with the same title or url. *usr* is the reddit PRAW object. When it starts to search with the url I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hargikas\Dropbox\Private\src\reddit\auto_poster\leftist.py", line 133, in <module>
    while (key is None) or find_if_posted(usr, key, content[key]):
  File "C:\Users\hargikas\Dropbox\Private\src\reddit\auto_poster\leftist.py", line 86, in find_if_posted
    for content in usr.search(url):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\praw\__init__.py", line 1108, in search
    **kwargs):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\praw\__init__.py", line 515, in get_content
    root = page_data.get(root_field, page_data)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Also when I am trying to post something (using the submit function) I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 372, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse(buffering=True)
TypeError: getresponse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 374, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1162, in getresponse
    raise ResponseNotReady(self.__state)
http.client.ResponseNotReady: Request-sent

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 597, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 245, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 309, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 374, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1162, in getresponse
    raise ResponseNotReady(self.__state)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ResponseNotReady('Request-sent',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hargikas\Dropbox\Private\src\reddit\auto_poster\leftist.py", line 140, in <module>
    usr.submit('greekreddit' , key, url=content[key])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\praw\decorators.py", line 338, in wrapped
    return function(cls, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\praw\decorators.py", line 237, in wrapped
    return function(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\praw\__init__.py", line 2218, in submit
    retry_on_error=False)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\praw\decorators.py", line 163, in wrapped
    return_value = function(reddit_session, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\praw\__init__.py", line 561, in request_json
    retry_on_error=retry_on_error)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\praw\__init__.py", line 402, in _request
    response = handle_redirect()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\praw\__init__.py", line 375, in handle_redirect
    timeout=timeout, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\praw\handlers.py", line 144, in wrapped
    result = function(cls, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\praw\handlers.py", line 54, in wrapped
    return function(cls, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\praw\handlers.py", line 99, in request
    allow_redirects=False)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ResponseNotReady('Request-sent',))
```

When I am searching using parameters of imgur.com or other "English" sites, I get no error. But when I use it over Greek sites, or posting Greek content I get the above errors.

Do you have an idea what I am doing wrong? I am a newbie with PRAW so any comment is appreciated. I am using *Python **3.4.3** (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32* and PRAW Version: ***2.1.21***

Thank you in advance!
Harry

Comment: What text did you try inputting into each field?  Also, have you been able to run the program before?  What is your user agent?  Do you regularly access reddit.com itself using a normal account?

Comment: @user1362215 Thanks for the quick reply. My previous program was only creating statistics for specific users. Not posting or searching. My User Agent is: 'Auto Poster for /u/leftist'. More Info on the function find_if_posted:
Trying with a URL that exists: https://i.imgur.com/fxYMc6V.gifv and I am getting the correct response.

Trying with this one: http://tvxs.gr/news/egrapsan-eipan/o-reporter-mia-epinoisi-tis-dekaetias-toy-1880 and I get the Error.